# Loading Torch7 trained models (.t7) in PyTorch

Tags: python, lua, pytorch, torch, pre-trained-model

I am using Torch7 library for implementing neural networks.  Mostly, I rely on pre-trained models. In Lua I use torch.load function to load a model saved as torch .t7 file. I am curious about switching to PyTorch( http://pytorch.org) and I read the documents. I couldn't find any information regarding the mechanisms to load a pre-trained model. The only relevant information I was able to find is this page:http://pytorch.org/docs/torch.html

But the function torch.load described in the page seems to load a file saved with pickle. If someone has additional information on loading .t7 models in PyTorch, please share it here.

Comment: have a look at: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/convert-import-torch-model-to-pytorch/37

Comment: @smhx Thanks a lot for the answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of PyTorch 1.0 `torch.utils.serialization` is completely removed. Hence no one can import models from Lua Torch into PyTorch anymore. Instead, I would suggest installing PyTorch 0.4.1 through `pip` in a `conda` environment (so that you can remove it after this) and use [this repo](https://github.com/clcarwin/convert_torch_to_pytorch) to convert your Lua Torch model to PyTorch model, not just the `torch.nn.legacy` model that you cannot use for training. Then use PyTorch 1.xx to do whatever with it. You can also train your converted Lua Torch models in PyTorch this way :)

Comment: Note: `convert_torch_to_pytorch` doesn't support LeakyReLU.

Comment: is there a way to install the dependency and do the operation on google colab, i tried but field!

Answer (score 7):

The correct function is `load_lua`:

```
from torch.utils.serialization import load_lua

x = load_lua('x.t7')
```

Comment: so after I get x, how can I use it?

Comment: @RockTheStar: You can use x.forward() just like other PyTorch models.

Comment: It should be noted that `load_lua` does not exist in PyTorch. Not sure if they removed it.

Comment: @oarfish  `torch.utils.serialization` is completely removed in PyTorch 1.0 onward.. Look at my answer above for an alternative solution.